# How to get h1 text into existing excel table Python

Tags: python, excel, beautifulsoup

I have some code that scrapes several tables from webpages and then puts the data into several excel files.

I want to also be able to add the company name at the bottom of the excel file. I have worked out how to get the name of the company using `companyname = soup.find('h1').text` as shown in the first code block below.

One of the excel files is generated from the following code lines:

```
all_data = {}
 #for every table found on the page
for table in soup.select('table.BordCollapseYear2'):
    table_name = table.find_previous('b').text
    all_data[table_name] = []
    #scrape for every row
    for tr in table.select('tr'):
        row = [td.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ') for td in tr.select('td')]
        if len(row) == 7:
            all_data[table_name].append(row)
companyname = soup.find('h1').text
```

```
with open('data2.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in all_data:
        spamwriter.writerow(row)
```

I tried adding the line `writerows(companyname)` this worked but it separated out each letter. So I think I am nearly there...

Answer (score 1):

Put `[]` around `companyname` in `writerow()`.

For example:

```
with open('data2.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in all_data:
        spamwriter.writerow(row)
    spamwriter.writerow([companyname])  # <-- notice the `[]` around companyname
```

Comment: Thanks! The [] turn it into a list right? It is working, I don't suppose there is a way I can tell it to print out the result in column B and write in column A the text "Company name" ?

Comment: @Mathlearner You can try `spamwriter.writerow(["Company name", companyname])`